# Configuring Transaction Manager in spring boot embedded tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, atomikos, transactionmanager, embedded-tomcat-8

I am using `Spring boot 1.2.3` with embedded `tomcat 8.0.20`.

In regular `tomcat` we can configure transaction manager in context.

**Example:**

```
<Transaction factory="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionFactory"/>
```

Is there any way that I can register T/X manager in `Spring boot` embedded `tomcat`?

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-jta.html for how to enable  atomicos transaction manager with spring boot.

Comment: I gone through this documentation. I am unable to configure T/X manager to bind in JNDI. All my implementation will try to fetch T/X manager from JNDI and use it(plain JDBC code. No JPA/JdbcTemplate or @Transactional annotations). Can you please point me how I can configure T/X manager and bind ti JNDI.